# c++ ordered(stable) priority queue

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, priority-queue

I am implementing a toy scheduler which reads a input file of process specifications such as arrival time, total run time and then schedules the process based on random io/cpu bursts.

The file is of the format

> Arrival time, total CPU time, CPU burst, IO Burst.

Now, when there are two process with same arrival time, the scheduler have to schedule the process first the process which is mentioned first in the file.

I am keeping the entries in the file in a priority queue.

```
struct EventComparator{
  bool operator()(const Event* event1, const Event* event2){
    return event1->getTimestamp() >= event2->getTimestamp();
  }   
};  
priority_queue<Event*, vector<Event*>, EventComparator> eventQueue;
```

where Event is just an object encapsulating the process parameters.

My problem is, the priority queue is not stable.  By stable I mean that the order of the process gets reversed.

Suppose the input file has

> 60 200  5   20
>
> 60  20  10  10
>
> 40 100  10  40
>
> 0  200  40  90

If i pop from the priority queue, I expect Line4, line 3, Line1 and then Line2.  But I get Line4, Line3, Line2, Line1.

My question is, what can I do to get a stable priority queue?

Comment: maybe you need to encode the file line in the information then in your comparison object check if the objects tie and if they do then use the file line information.  Otherwise use the time-stamp for the comparison.

Comment: Most standard containers don't bother enforcing stability.  It's easiest to simply add additional information to guarantee ordering as @NathanOliver suggests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Your comparator is incorrect. The [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) for the `std::priority_queue` states that it should provide a strict weak ordering(that is, it should `event1->getTimestamp() > event2->getTimestamp()`, not `>=`).
2. To make it stable, you can just store the line number inside the `Event` and compare it if `event1->getTimestamp() == event2->getTimestamp()`.

Something like this:

```
struct EventComparator {
  bool operator()(const Event* event1, const Event* event2) {
    if (event1->getTimestamp() != event2->getTimestamp()) {
      return event1->getTimestamp() > event2->getTimestamp();
    }
    return event1->getLineNumber() > event2->getLineNumber();
  }   
};
```

Comment: Sounds so easy now.  I dont know why I didn't think of this before.  And thanks for pointing out the strict weak ordering.